# DQL ORDER BY is not working with negative numbers

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

I am using the DQL query:

```
SELECT NEW PodcastBundle:PodcastDTO(p.id, p.title, SUM(ue.rating)) FROM 
PodcastBundle:UserEpisode ue
JOIN PodcastBundle:Episode e WITH ue.episode = e
JOIN PodcastBundle:Podcast p WITH e.podcast = p
WHERE ue.user = :user
GROUP BY p
ORDER BY ue.rating DESC
```

'ue.rating' just holds numeric values which can also be negative. But when looping through the results the order is [1, 0, -4, 1].

Does anyone know the query I should use to display them in a numeric order. I guess that the query sorts them in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Doctrine creates internally normal SQL query, you can preview it by `$query->getSQL()`.

Note that it uses standard `ORDER BY` in the resulting SQL. So either it's a problem with your engine (check that out by manually by running that query) or problem with Query Hydration.

If the first issue proves to be correct you can try writing [your own ordering function in DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html) or using NativeQuery.

If the latter seems to be at fault you can either write your own Hydrator (hard, undocumented) or resort into **not** using NEW and creating objects by hand using something like ArrayHydration.

Comment: Thank you, the same error occurred when I ran the SQL in PHPMyAdmin so it's definitely an MySQL error. Thanks for the link to custom ordering functions in DQL.